# How can I detect and utilize left and right swipe gestures on a RelativeLayout to call functions?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

So far I have created a RelativeLayout as below, which holds 6 Text-views (but only 3 are visible at any one time). Upon button press of either of the two circular Image-views those Text-views are made visible or invisible appropriately.

What I would also like to happen, but as yet I don't know how is: for when the use swipes left anywhere on the RelativeLayout holding the textviews it would be as though the first circular Image-view had been pressed and it the user swipes right anywhere on the Image-view, it would be as though the user had selected the second circular Image-view.

I have not used gestures in this fashion on RelativeLayouts before, so help would be much appreciated. Thanks

My code so far:

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView firstCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.firstCircle);
        final ImageView  secondCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secondCircle);
        final TextView  textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final TextView  textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        final TextView  textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        final TextView  textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        final TextView  textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        final TextView  textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        firstCircle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                textView5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                textView6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        });

        secondCircle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                textView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                textView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                textView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/resultsBox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#2afd24">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="tables"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="tables"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="tables"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="chairs"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="chairs"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="chairs"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/firstCircle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/secondCircle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#fff"/>

    <size
        android:width="18dp"
        android:height="18dp"/>
</shape>
```

**What app looks like so far:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should do the job :-)**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private int viewLeftMargin;
    private int viewTopMargin;
    private int viewBottomMargin;
    private int viewRightMargin;
    private int lastMarginLeft;
    private int lastMarginRight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView firstCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.firstCircle);
        final ImageView  secondCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secondCircle);
        final TextView  textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final TextView  textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        final TextView  textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        final TextView  textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        final TextView  textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        final TextView  textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        firstCircle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                firstCircleClick();
            }
        });

        secondCircle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                secondCircleClick();
            }
        });



        RelativeLayout resultsBox = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.resultsBox);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) resultsBox
                .getLayoutParams();
        lastMarginLeft = lParams.leftMargin;
        lastMarginRight = lParams.rightMargin;

        resultsBox.setOnTouchListener(
                new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
                        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

                        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v
                                        .getLayoutParams();
                                viewLeftMargin = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                                viewTopMargin = lParams.topMargin;
                                viewBottomMargin = lParams.bottomMargin;
                                viewRightMargin = X - lParams.rightMargin;
                                break;

                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v
                                        .getLayoutParams();
                                layoutParams.rightMargin = X - viewRightMargin;
                                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - viewLeftMargin;
                                layoutParams.topMargin = viewTopMargin;
                                layoutParams.bottomMargin = viewBottomMargin;

                                if (layoutParams.leftMargin <= lastMarginLeft) {
                                    Log.d("ON_TOUCH", "Moving to left!");

                                    secondCircleClick();
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("ON_TOUCH", "Moving to right!");
                                    firstCircleClick();
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        );

    }

    public void firstCircleClick(){
        textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        textView5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        textView6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void secondCircleClick(){
        textView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        textView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        textView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        textView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
Declare

```
private float lastX;
```

as member variable.

Add this method to handle onTouch

```
/***********************************************
 * TouchEventListener
 ***********************************************/
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {

    if (!isForcedSleep) {
        switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_LEFT: {
            lastY = touchevent.getX();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_RIGHT: {
            float currentY = touchevent.getX());

            if (lastX < currentX - 15) {
                //Do your stuff

            } else if (lastX > currentX + 15) {
                //Do your stuff
            }
            break;
        }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```